# Permanently change ownership of loop devices

Tags: slackware

How could I let normal user become the owner of the loop devices?

I tried with `chown`, but whenever the device is being detached with `losetup -d` if afterward being created then again automatically owned by root. How can I permanently change the ownership?

I'm using Slackware 13.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use udev rules. However, on my system the group is set to `disk`, and you just have to add a user to the `disk` group to use it. I'm not sure if Ubuntu works this way, but you can check.